# What are good Dropwizard database config defaults when using Oracle in production?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling, dropwizard

What settings from the following reference would be sensible for well behaved connection pools connecting to a large Oracle production database where both connection setup times and typical queries can be relatively long (more than a few seconds...).

- http://www.dropwizard.io/manual/configuration.html#database

Similar tips on thin driver specific config properties (below) that are worth using would be useful too.

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

I'm particularly interested in Dropwizard 7 and Oracle 11gR2 with the JDBC thin driver (ojdbc6.jar), but generally applicable tips would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

About the max size of your connection pool you need to be careful not to use a too high number because it may have a large negative impact on the database. The default value for maxSize is 100 which is a reasonable number. There is a golden rule that says that the total number of connections to Oracle shouldn't be more than 20 times the number of threads (usually each core has two threads). Also establishing brand new connections to Oracle is expensive so depending on your needs you may need to consider a higher number than 10 for minSize. It's always best to keep a small number of always-busy connections to the database.